# How to update data in database without using several queries?

Tags: database

In my application, it shows student's subject and it's result. First, I have written this application to show the subject and results only. But, now we need to extend it's functionality to update subjects results from admin panel.

Problem is in my database, I have recorded results, if the student has taken-part in the given subject. As an example if a student is absent for mathematics, in the application subject will be printed without results for mathematics.

What I need is to update the results for each student. What I have noticed was, I need to write update, insert and delete queries to update student's results.

I don't want to handle 3 queries. I am looking for more flexible way of doing this.

One solution, I came across is, update database manually. That is if the student is absent for any given subject, update results to 0 and keep the record. so in admin panel, I need to use only update query.I am not sure where this is ok from database concepts.

Is there any better solutions?

Comment: why is this question down voted? if the question is not clear let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your question... may be this will be useful check this one

```
$var=1;
update tablename set col=col+$var
```

you can directly add value without retrieving previous value.